# Clion vs Visual Studio Community 2019 for c++ dev work

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, c++

So Iam having a hard time choosing between visual studio 2019 community and clion, mainly because Iam debating if I should get m1mac mini or a windows machine. Can someone explain the main difference and negatives / positives between the 2 IDEs?

( In regards to using for c++ development )

Comment: It probably depends what you're building for… you can't build for Mac or iOS on a Windows machine. On an Intel Mac you can build for Windows as well [I'm not sure how that's panning out for the M1 Macs as yet]

Comment: It’s just console applications for university I don’t plan to use it for major projects just for university only really, do you recon clion will be fine for that?